# How can I send Data with JSON to Sqlite

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

I'm working on a mobile application using Jquery Mobile & Phonegap. 
I used to send data to a server but now I want to make it locally stored using sqlite. 
What I made before was :

```
            function CallUpdate(varx) {
            var postData = { 'Function': '...', 'Varx': JSON.stringify(varx) };
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: serviceUrl + "/datagathering.aspx",
                data: postData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert('Your changes have been saved!');
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }
```

Now I won't send any data to the server, I just have a javascript file in which I put my database & functions. 
So how can I send the data to the sqlite database ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the available [SQLite plugins](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phonegap/YIVTvW6j2k4)

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile browsers (webkit based) still support the [webSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database) implementation; something that I wouldn't usually recommend you using due to the development of it as a specification being ceased by the W3C. However, with regards to PhoneGap - this is currently the method which the documentation actually *advises* you to use.

In PhoneGap you access it using the same methods that you would use for the web specification - [To quote the PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html):

> This API is based on the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C
>   Web Storage API Specification. Some devices already provide an
>   implementation of this spec. For those devices, the built-in support
>   is used instead of replacing it with PhoneGap's implementation. For
>   devices that don't have storage support, PhoneGap's implementation
>   should be compatible with the W3C specification.

This saves the use of external plugins, is cross-platform and fits in to the PhoneGap methodology of keeping all code in Javascript/HTML whilst adhering to simplicity.